# Reactjs Single-spa CssSyntaxError

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, single-spa

In my webpack.config.js I put the code for css-loader and file-loader after I install them

```
  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

this is the error I encounter so far

> ERROR in ./src/App.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> CssSyntaxError
>
> (2:7)
> C:\Users\Mitchy\Desktop\MitchyTutorial\CRA-TEST\cra-test\src\App.css
> Unknown word
>
> 1 |   2 |       import API from
> "!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
> |       ^   3 |       import domAPI from "!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";   4 |
> import insertFn from
> "!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";  @
> ./src/App.css 8:6-205 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64
> 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-175
> 83:0-175 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64 61:4-74:5  @ ./src/App.js 2:0-19
> @ ./src/orig-name-cra-test.tsx 4:0-27 9:17-20
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> CssSyntaxError
>
> (2:7)
> C:\Users\Mitchy\Desktop\MitchyTutorial\CRA-TEST\cra-test\src\index.css
> Unknown word
>
> 1 |   2 |       import API from
> "!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
> |       ^   3 |       import domAPI from "!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";   4 |
> import insertFn from
> "!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";  @
> ./src/index.css 8:6-207 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64
> 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-177
> 83:0-177 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64 61:4-74:5  @
> ./src/orig-name-cra-test.tsx 5:0-21
>
> webpack 5.60.0 compiled with 2 errors in 2661 ms

Comment: Can you console.log out the config before returning it? webpack-merge operates by merging arrays by default so the first problem is going to be that you have multiple rules that handle .css files.

Comment: The second problem will be that you will need to use webpack-merge's `mergeWithRules` https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge#mergewithrules to combine the two sets of rules. I have an example of this here https://github.com/filoxo/single-spa-example-webpack-lazystyletag/blob/main/webpack.config.js#L4-L16 but your question doesn't include enough context to know if it'll do exactly what you're looking to so you might need to tweak the behavior.